# Conexión MS SQL con Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, sql-server

Tengo un problema para conectar mi aplicación a una base de datos MS SQL.

Estoy usando la librería mssql la cual instalé mediante npm. Cuanto intento conectarme mediante SSMS (Administrador de servidor sql) no hay problema, pero luego intento hacerlo con las mismas credenciales usando la librería y me arroja el siguiente error.

```
Error de inicio de sesión del usuario '<aquí va el usuario>'.
```

El código que estoy usando para la conexión es el siguiente.

```
const mssql = require('mssql')

co(function*(){

    try{
        let dbConfig = {
            "server":"AUTOMAT\\SQLSYSWIN",
            "user":"nano",
            "password":"xxxxxxx",
        }

        let db = yield mssql.connect(dbConfig)

    }catch(err){
        console.error(err.stack)
    }
})
```

Pienso que puede ser una configuración de la base de datos. Alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: Cuando te conectas con el Administrador, lo haces usar autentificación de windows o autentificación de sql?

Comment: Creo que lo que te esta pasando es que tienes al servicio de SQL corriendo solo con autenticación de windows. Tienes que activarle la seguridad mixta con Windows y SQL server en la pestaña seguridad en las propiedades del servidor

Answer (score 1):

Mira, estoy trabajando con ello y ami me funciono así;

```
var dbconfig = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: '123',
    server: 'Alonso-L4PT0P',
    database: 'ProyectoSQLAplicadoTR'
}
```

Por lo que veo , tus datos de configuración están erróneos, Es primero el usuario luego lo demás (como ves en mi configuración), El usuario que pones tiene que ser de un usuario del SQL SERVER (en mi caso use el "sa") y no debe ser el usuario actual del windows , luego la contraseña xxxx que pusiste no creo que sea la correcta.Finalmente, en server tienes "//" es posible que no te capte bien el servidor(me paso ami) así que te recomiendo que uses la instancia "AUTOMAT" de tu SQL SERVER.

Espero haberte ayudado , Suerte!

Comment: La forma de validación en SQL, puede ser a través de un usuario SQL, como es tu caso con el SA, o bien con un usuario de WIndows, que es lo que esta usando @user3932. Ademas lo que comentas de la contraseña, es de suponer que por temas de seguridad, no la quiera poner y la cambie por xxxx